# Able to find the row using row name string on a dataframe but "%in%" and "which" function are not able to find the same in the rownames() vector?

Tags: r

```
stms["a",] # this is giving me the corresponding row in stms
"a" %in% rownames(stms) # this is giving me false
which("a" == rownames(stms)) # this is giving me integer(0)
```

Please let me know what can be the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial matching happens on the rownames when they can be uniquely identified.

See this example -

```
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = rnorm(5), 
                 row.names = c('a1', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2'))
df
#             a          b
#a1 -0.23017749  0.4609162
#b1  1.55870831 -1.2650612
#b2  0.07050839 -0.6868529
#c1  0.12928774 -0.4456620
#c2  1.71506499  1.2240818

#subset on 'a'
df['a', ]
#            a         b
#a1 -0.2301775 0.4609162

"a" %in% rownames(df) 
#[1] FALSE

which("a" == rownames(df)) 
#integer(0)
```

Does not work for 'b' since value of 'b' cannot be uniquely identified so we don't know if it is row 2 or row3.

```
df['b', ]
#    a  b
#NA NA NA
```

Comment: is there a way to specify that we need exact match and not partial match? I know we can use the which and other functions but the line becomes big and confusing.

Comment: Unfortunately , I did not find a way to do this. You may use `df[rownames(df) == 'a1', ]`

Comment: If someone is facing similar issue. I solved this issue using the "match" function instead of calling using row names.